# How can i deny activity to be destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, destroy

I'm starting the activity "B" from the activity "A". When I'm closing the activity B using the back button or method finish(), the activity  A is recreating. How can i deny activity to be destroyed?

Comment: what you want to do??

Comment: Yes, that is expected behaviour. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: You can't. You have to write your app to cope with it.

Comment: I know this lifecycle. But I heard it is possible to break the cycle.

Comment: @Ingvar it's possible to manipulate the activity stack not activity lifecycle, see my asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Activities in android are stored in a Stack called activity-stack, when you go to next Activity it's added to the stack, when you go back you pop last element from stack and nothing points at it any more, so **not destroying** is just waste of space!

Even if you override the back button to launch previous activity with `noHistory` or `clearTop` flag, current activity would be destroyed.

I suggest that you read more on [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)